# Reprojecting: trouble converting MapInfo data to shapefiles in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, coordinate-system, mapinfo, wgs84

I was given a dataset generated in MapInfo. I need to use these files in QGIS, so I imported the .TAB files and saved them as ESRI shapefiles. I then realised the original dataset uses a custom "user defined" CRS. When I change the CRS from this user defined system to WGS84 in QGIS, serious positional errors arise! The shape is also wildly altered.

I tried converting the MapInfo data to ESRI shapefiles using ogr2gui and got the same results.
[image: User_defined_CRS_from_MapInfo_causing_trouble_in_QGIS]

How can I reproject the data to overcome the positional and shape errors? Is there a way of changing the original MapInfo CRS to WGS84, ensuring the shape and desired positioning will be correct in QGIS?

Comment: A different shape can arise due to distortion of different map projections which can be illustrated with a [Tissot's indicatrix](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/03/24/tissot-s-indicatrix-helps-illustrate-map-projection-distortion/)

Comment: Based on the proj4 string, it's a Brunei or Borneo CRS. The values look a bit funky. You might try using EPSG:29873 if it's supported.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change projection when saving the file to another format (TAB to Shapefile). Right-click the tab file -> go to save as, the following window will appear:

[image]

In the red box, select the target projection here, then save the file to shapefile.

If the output shapfile did not give you the desired results with a correct location, this means that the original custom CRS is not recognized by QGIS. In this case you may need to define a new CRS and enter the correct parameter which must conform with the proj4 format.

To do that go to `Settings -> Custom CRS` Click on Plus sign and define the parameters.

Comment: Just to add: If you misused `Set Layer CRS` for the task, change it back **before** you `Save As ...`, or delete the layer and re-add it to the project.